# Extract data from Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) using SQL query

Tags: t-sql, windows-update

I have never used WSUS, so I really dont know how to get right data. The goal is to have a table with three columns: **Computer Group, Computer Name, # of needed updates**

I found out here: [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410149%28VS.85%29.aspx)
that WSUS uses SQL server to store data that I need and I can connect to it via **\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query**. I prefer this method, not PowerShell or something else, because finally I need this data in other sqlserver.

Could somebody please help me with SQL query that will extract needed info? I cant see anything familiar in database or PUBLIC_VIEWs. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using SUSDB, here is a summary **by computer** with more columns that you requested:

```
With cteUpdateInstallationInfo As(
 SELECT u.UpdateID
 , ct.ComputerID 
 , (CASE WHEN usc.SummarizationState IS NULL OR usc.SummarizationState = 1 THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL(u.LastUndeclinedTime, u.ImportedTime) < ct.EffectiveLastDetectionTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE usc.SummarizationState END) AS State
  FROM       dbo.tbUpdate AS u 
  JOIN       dbo.tbRevision AS r ON u.LocalUpdateID = r.LocalUpdateID And r.IsLatestRevision = 1
  JOIN       dbo.tbProperty AS p ON r.RevisionID = p.RevisionID And p.ExplicitlyDeployable = 1
  CROSS JOIN dbo.tbComputerTarget AS ct 
  LEFT JOIN  dbo.tbUpdateStatusPerComputer AS usc ON u.LocalUpdateID = usc.LocalUpdateID AND ct.TargetID = usc.TargetID
  WHERE u.IsHidden = 0
), Summary as(
  Select ComputerId
  , Count(*)  as Total
  , Sum(case When State = 0 Then 1 else 0 end)       as NoStatus
  , Sum(case When State = 1 Then 1 else 0 end)       as NotApp
  , Sum(case When State In(2,3,6) Then 1 else 0 end) as Needed
  , Sum(case When State = 4 Then 1 else 0 end)       as Installed
  , Sum(case When State = 5 Then 1 else 0 end)       as Failed
  From cteUpdateInstallationInfo
  Group by ComputerId
), TimeZone as (
 Select DATEDIFF(mi, GetUtcDate(), GetDate()) as TimeZoneMinutes
)
Select ct.ComputerId
, ct.FullDomainName 
, ct.IPAddress
, tg.Name as TargetGroupName
, Total, NoStatus, NotApp, Needed, Failed, Installed
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, ct.EffectiveLastDetectionTime) As LastDetectLocalTime
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, ct.LastReportedStatusTime) as LastReportLocalTime
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, ct.LastSyncTime) As LastContactLocalTime
, LastSyncResult    

, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, ct.LastReportedRebootTime) As LastRebootLocalTime
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, ct.LastInventoryTime) As LastInventoryLocalTime
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, ct.LastNameChangeTime) As LastNameChangeLocalTime
--, IsRegistered
--, OSMajorVersion, OSMinorVersion, OSBuildNumber, OSServicePackMajorNumber,OSServicePackMinorNumber
, OSLocale
, ComputerMake
, ComputerModel
, BiosVersion
, BiosName
, BiosReleaseDate
, ProcessorArchitecture
--, LastStatusRollupTime    LastReceivedStatusRollupNumber  LastSentStatusRollupNumber
--, SamplingValue, CreatedTime, SuiteMask, OldProductType, NewProductType, SystemMetrics
, ClientVersion
--, TargetGroupMembershipChanged
, OSFamily
, OSDescription
, OEM
, DeviceType
, FirmwareVersion
, MobileOperator    
From Summary as s 
Join TimeZone as tz on 1=1
JOIN dbo.tbComputerTarget AS ct on ct.ComputerID = s.ComputerId
Join tbComputerTargetDetail ctd on ctd.TargetId = ct.TargetId
Join tbTargetInTargetGroup tgct on tgct.TargetId = ct.TargetId
Join tbTargetGroup tg on tg.TargetGroupId = tgct.TargetGroupId
```

Also as a bonus here is a summary **by update**:

```
With Summary as(
  Select UpdateId
  , Count(*)  as Total
  , Sum(case When State = 0 Then 1 else 0 end)     as NoStatus
  , Sum(case When State = 1 Then 1 else 0 end)     as NotApp
  , Sum(case When State In(2,3,6) Then 1 else 0 end) as Needed
  , Sum(case When State = 4 Then 1 else 0 end)     as Installed
  , Sum(case When State = 5 Then 1 else 0 end)     as Failed
  From PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateInstallationInfo
  Group BY UpdateId
), TimeZone as (
 Select DATEDIFF(mi, GetUtcDate(), GetDate()) as TimeZoneMinutes
)
Select s.UpdateId
, u.IsDeclined
, u.PublicationState
, u.DefaultTitle as Title
, u.KnowledgebaseArticle as KBArticle
, Total, NoStatus, NotApp, Needed, Failed, Installed 
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, u.CreationDate) As ReleaseLocalTime
, Dateadd(mi, TimeZoneMinutes, u.ArrivalDate) As ArrivalLocalTime
From summary as s
Join TimeZone as tz on 1=1
Join PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate as u on u.UpdateID = s.UpdateId
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **SUSDB** here is a minimal version with columns you requested:

```
Select tg.Name as ComputerGroup, ct.FullDomainName as ComputerName, Count(*) As Needed
From tbComputerTarget AS ct 
Join tbComputerTargetDetail ctd on ctd.TargetId = ct.TargetId
Join tbTargetInTargetGroup tgct on tgct.TargetId = ct.TargetId
Join tbTargetGroup tg on tg.TargetGroupId = tgct.TargetGroupId
Join tbUpdateStatusPerComputer as s on ct.TargetID = s.TargetID And SummarizationState In(2,3,6)
Group By tg.Name, ct.FullDomainName;
```